# Tools to manage Windows Azure Active Directory users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Other than the Azure Portal, are there any tools to manage users in a Windows Azure Active Directory?

Comment: PowerShell: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj151815.aspx

Comment: Do you have a specific need or scenario? (Also, this might be better asked over on ServerFault, as it's not a programming question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As things stand there are no useful tools from Microsoft to manage WaaD outside code/scripting.
There is a WaaD portal but its about to be retired (if it hadn't been already) and I haven't seen any announcement about a replacement.

One can also use the O365 admin portal to manage O365 related tenant, but, like the Azure management portal, this provides access to more that just managing the WaaD tenant.

Comment: Which portal are you referring to that is about to be retired? The ACTIVE DIRECTORY section in the Azure management portal (https://manage.windowsazure.net) is not about to be retired.

Comment: I never said the AD section of the Azure management portal is being retired, the portal that used to be dedicated to managing users in a tenant - https://activedirectory.windowsazure.com IIRC, is no longer

Comment: I see what you mean. Yes, that portal is soon to be retired in favor of the more complete version of it which is a part of the Azure portal.

Comment: The challenge with relying on the Azure management portal is the all-or-nothing permissions on it. we need, on several occasions, a tool for somebody to ONLY be able to manage AD users and groups. the management portal is not a good idea at all. perhaps when RBAC is there it would make more sense, until then there's a big gap.

Comment: I see what you mean, that's a good point. To be clear, we're talking all-or-nothing as far as AAD is concerned, right? (Because there's technically no relationship between the AAD and other Azure resources.)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, each has its pros and cons depending on your requirements:

- The 'Azure Active Directory' section of the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)
- The 'Users' section of the [Office 365 portal](https://portal.office.com)
- The Azure AD PowerShell modules: [MSOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0) (v1) or [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) (v2) (scripting)
- The [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) (programmatic access)
- The [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) (programmatic access)

Note: If you have Active Directory on-premises and are synchronizing to your Azure Active Directory tenant, I guess that could also be viewed as a management tool.